# data rebinding issue

Tags: android, android-databinding

I have a project built on data binding. But due to some reason, I lost my build folder. Now in order to regenerate those classes, I need to rebuild my project but it won't build because it can't find layout binding classes already in use. 
Is there a solution which can avoid commenting out my code to build the project again to regenerate data binding code.

Comment: Did you try Rebuild that project?

Comment: Can you tell us more about your dev environment?  What tools are you using?

Comment: Whenever I try to rebuild, the compiler can't find layout binding classes that were generated before and build fails.

Comment: I am using android studio 3.1.3

Answer (score 0):

close project and from project folder delete .iml file then reopen your project